# How to add or edit a child in parent view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new in MVC. I display the parent view details in two parts, the details and a list of child. But now I want add the possibility to add an other child to this parent in the same view. I use : 
controller

```
public ViewResult Details(long id)
    {
        Parent x = db.Parent.Find(id);
        return View(x);
    }
```

view :

```
@model  MyProject_v0_2.Models.Parent

<table id="details">
....
</table>

<table id="lstChild">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Child)
            {...}
</table>
```

I want add a button here which let me add a child in this view. I can add a table that I display or not with all the child data, but I don't know I to save it.
In the future I will need to change some Parent properties so I can't change the model type.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the [following article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) which illustrates a nice way of how to achieve this task. It uses javascript on the client to add/delete rows. It also uses a custom `Html.BeginCollectionItem` helper which allows for generating non sequential indexes for the collection input field names.